# Deleting an empty file, why there are so many sys calls ?

Tags: linux, rm, strace

Try to create an empty file and strace the operations that are involved to delete it. The list is very long:

```
touch a
strace rm a
execve("/bin/rm", ["rm", "a"], [/* 20 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x65f000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd579b94000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=25132, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 25132, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd579b8d000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\37\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1840928, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3949248, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd5795af000
mprotect(0x7fd57976a000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fd579969000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1ba000) = 0x7fd579969000
mmap(0x7fd57996f000, 17088, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd57996f000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd579b8c000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd579b8a000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fd579b8a740) = 0
mprotect(0x7fd579969000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x60d000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fd579b96000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fd579b8d000, 25132)           = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x65f000
brk(0x680000)                           = 0x680000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2919792, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2919792, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd5792e6000
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "a", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
geteuid()                               = 1000
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "a", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "a", W_OK)          = 0
unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "a", 0)              = 0
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Why is that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of the system calls that appear above the `close(3)` call are due to dynamic library loading. It looks like it's also checking for any cached dynamicly linkable libraries, too.

The system calls to actually remove the file begin with the `newfstatat()` call, and include 4 other system calls. The 3 `close()` calls and the `exit_group()` are the C-runtime doing cleanup after the `main()` function of `rm` returns or exits.

To editorialize just a bit, this is the kind of thing that makes people wish for statically-linked executables, and try various things like [sta.li](http://sta.li/) or [Morpheus](http://morpheus.2f30.org/).

Comment: just out of curiosity, any idea why anyone would really want a dynamically linked `rm`? maybe for some special arg parsing or something... for a more simple example - even my GNU `unlink` is dynamically linked. maybe its off topic, but maybe you know, too?

Comment: I believe, but will change my opinion if facts warrant, that the idea is every program uses a whole lot of common code. If it's already in memory, the kernel can just map that code (libc for example) into a new process, rather than reading it from disk, and using yet another page of RAM. There's also desirable side effects, like updating `/usr/lib/libc.so` and magically, every program has a security patch (or whatever). I don't know how much the side effects played into making everything dynamically linked.

Comment: Yes, probably so. After commenting I vaguely remembered someone mentioning licensing headaches - especially where glibc is concerned - regarding dynamic/static linking. I guess the GPL could get in the way of simplicity sometimes.

Comment: I'd be curious to have a more detailed breakdown of the different lines.